# Can the CSV module parse files with multi-character delimiters?

Tags: python, csv

I have a "CSV" file that uses a multi-character delimiter, so the data looks something like

```
field1_|#|_field2_|#|_field3_|#|_field4
```

Is there a way to use the Python CSV module to parse this file?

Comment: Related: [How to use python csv module for splitting double pipe delimited data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6352409/how-to-use-python-csv-module-for-splitting-double-pipe-delimited-data)

Comment: use pandas `pd.read_csv(file.csv, sep='\|#\|', engine='python')`.

Answer (score 6):

Try to replace the multichar delimiter with the singlechar one.

Somethin like this:

```
class DelimitedFile:
  def __init__(self, fname, mode='rb', ind=',', outd=','):
    self.f = open(fname, mode)
    self.ind = ind
    self.outd = outd

  def __iter__(self):
    return self

  def next(self):
    line = self.f.next()
    return line.replace(self.ind, self.outd)
```

Use it like so:

```
import csv

delimiter = ','

reader = csv.reader(DelimitedFile(fileName, ind='_|#|_', outd=delimiter))

for row in reader:
  print row
```

Answer (score 1):

Python's csv module cannot process delimiters of more than one character, so the short answer to "Can the Python CSV module parse files with multi-column delimiters?" is "no".  A simple test confirmed this:

```
reader = csv.reader(open('test.csv'), delimiter = '|#|')
```

Which resulted in this error:

> TypeError: "delimiter" must be an 1-character string

(test.csv was a 2 row file with delimiters as shown in the code.)

Thus you'll either need to replace your delimiters with single character delimiters as @alexblum suggested, write your own parser, or find a different parser.  Googling 'python csv multi-character delimiter' turned up hits to a few.