# Searching for and editing values in a 2 tab delimited text file python 3

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to create a program that will find values above `353.7000` in the third column of a text file and change them to `353.7000`.

The one obstacle I know I have is the file is delimited by 2 tabs between the columns. That is why I was trying to use `DictReader` to get the field names and pass them to `DictWriter`, but I have obviously not succeeded in making that work.

Currently the program just takes the data file and makes it blank. No errors or simply just leaves the edited file blank. In a few versions back(I haven't been saving copies like a doofus) I realized the problem with it being two tab delimited and I was getting a value error.

It is essential that I maintain formatting on the text file as it has to be read by an existing program that expects it in that format.

Here's [an example](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/ebe4bed8087dae8897f6f672fd3a16bc) of the data file.

Here's the code:

```
import os
import sys
import csv

AMplateNum = input("Please Scan AM-DNA plate barcode AM******-DNA: ")
NormFileName = AMplateNum + ".txt"
FileToChange = "E:\\NormalizeData\\" + NormFileName
#this prompts user to scan in AM barcode then builds the file path

def check_value_to_edit(value):
    if float(value) > 353.7000:
        value = "353.7000"
    return value
    else:
    return value
#check_value_to_edit evaluates a "value" as a float and changes it to 353.7
#if the value exceeds it
def get_destination_dictwriter(file):
    with open(FileToChange, 'r') as source:
        csv_source = csv.DictReader(source, delimiter='\t')
        fieldnames = csv_source.fieldnames
        dictwriter = csv.DictWriter(file, fieldnames=fieldnames)
        return dictwriter

destination = open(FileToChange, 'w', newline='')    
csv_destination = get_destination_dictwriter(destination)

with open(FileToChange, 'r') as source:
        csv_source = csv.DictReader(source, delimiter='\t')
        for row in csv_source:
            row["Concentration"] = check_value_to_edit(row)
            csv_destination.writerow(row)  


destination.close()
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on how this isn't working? Do you get any errors? What goes wrong? Do you get some unexpected output? Please include this in your question.

Comment: I think you are on your own when it comes to multi character delimiters. I don't think csv or pandas supports those. What you could do is either write your own bespoke parser or preformat the file to replace the double tab with a single tab on the fly (not changing the actual file) and feed that to dict reader. You'd have to be sure though that a single tab isn't used somewhere in your file. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6352409/how-to-use-python-csv-module-for-splitting-double-pipe-delimited-data) question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the two methods I mentioned in my comment.

```
from csv import DictReader


def printdictlist(dl):
    for i in dl:
        print('--------------')
        for k, v in i.items():
            print('{0} - {1}'.format(k, v))

''' Method 1 - replace double tab '''
with open('dbltab.csv') as f:
    dr = DictReader((line.replace('\t\t', '\t') for line in f), delimiter='\t')

    printdictlist(dr)

''' Method 2 - roll your own parser '''
with open('dbltab.csv') as f:
    try:
        topline = next(f).strip().split('\t\t')
    except StopIteration:
        pass

    d = [dict(zip(topline, line.strip().split('\t\t'))) for line in f]

    printdictlist(d)
```