# two columns in csv files getting read as single column. python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

i have 2 CSV files. i want each element in list A to get matched with every element in the list B. list A acts as training set and the list B has error which get fixed after getting matched using edit distance.

the problem is there are two columns in B. first column has unique numbers and second column has the string to be fixed.

im getting the output as :

```
628227teitARMTEteke : iQIARMTEMAC
628226iQIARMTEMAC 9 : iQIARMTEMAC
628229iQIAConfigCH : iQIAConfigCH
627701iQIAConfigCH : iQIAConfigCH
```

but i want my output to be:

```
628227 : teitARMTEteke : iQIARMTEMAC
628226 : iQIARMTEMAC 9 : iQIARMTEMAC
628229 : iQIAConfigCH : iQIAConfigCH
627701 : iQIAConfigCH : iQIAConfigCH
```

**CODE**

```
import csv
from nltk.metrics import distance


with open("all_correct_promo.csv","rb") as file1:
    reader1 = csv.reader(file1)
    correctPromoList = [''.join(i) for i in reader1]
   # print correctPromoList
with open("all_extracted_promo3.csv","rb") as file2:
    reader2 = csv.reader(file2)
    extractedPromoList = [''.join(i) for i in reader2]
    #print extractedPromoList

incorrectPromo = {}
count = 0
for extracted in extractedPromoList:
    #print 'Computing %dth promo code...' % count
    incorrectPromo[extracted] =  find_min_edit(extracted,correctPromoList) # get comma separated str of real promo codes nearest to extracted
    count+=1
#print incorrectPromo


for key, value in incorrectPromo.iteritems():
    print key ,':', value
```

Right now the unique numbers are getting read with the strings which will effect the way the string get corrected. i want the numbers to be displayed with its string but without effecting the way the string is getting matched with the strings in list A.

sample from all_extracted_promo3.csv

```
628229  iQIABundUPGR
628229  iQIAPortUPGR
628229  iQIAConfigCH
628229  iQIARMTEMAC 9
```

sample from all_correct_promo.csv

```
iQ BundleUPGR
IQ MANAGED
IQ04 BRP
IQ1MOBILSUP
IQ2MOBILSUP
iQBundIeUPGR
iQBundle 1
iQBundle 2
```

Comment: What is list A?

Comment: all_correct_promo.csv - will be list A

Comment: I am a bit confused. The string with the numbers, it is coming from `all_correct_promo.csv`, you want to do the distance calculation on the string without the numbers?

Comment: all_correct_promo.csv has one column with correct strings.
all_extracted_promo.csv has 2 columns. one with id numbers and other column with strings to be matched for distance calculation.

i want the strings to be matched and in out to display first both the column contents of all_extracted_promo and then the answer taken from all_correct_promo

Comment: Please update your question and put a sample line from `all_correct_promo.csv` and `all_extracted_promo.csv`

Comment: done. please check now

Answer (score 1):

Leaving aside a strange way of getting the data - to say the least - that you use, I'll answer strictly about `csv.reader`.

For `csv.reader` to distinguish columns, you need to set up its `dialect` in accordance with your `.csv`. As [its docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html?highlight=csv.reader#csv.reader) say, it accepts all invividual [dialect formatting parameters](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html?highlight=csv.reader#csv-fmt-params) as keyword arguments. Here, you're probably interested in `delimeter`:

```
csv.reader(<file>,delimeter=<whatever>)
```

Judging by the excerpts, your `all_extracted_promo3.csv` has two spaces for delimiter, and `all_correct_promo.csv` uses a single space. [`csv.Reader` only supports single-character delimiters though](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6352409/how-to-use-python-csv-module-for-splitting-double-pipe-delimited-data):

```
>>> [i for i in csv.reader(open("all_extracted_promo3.csv","rb"),delimiter=' ')]
[['628229', '', 'iQIABundUPGR'],
 ['628229', '', 'iQIAPortUPGR'],
 ['628229', '', 'iQIAConfigCH'],
 ['628229', '', 'iQIARMTEMAC', '9']]
```

So you'll have to either get around that (by ignoring the 2nd element), change the software that produces the file - e.g. to use the standard comma as delimiter - or use some other facility to parse the file.